# Lambda Calculus Syntax - Brackets between $\lambda$ and dot

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

I just realised that I have a very trivial/basic question concerning the syntax of Lambda Calculus.

> **Question 1:** Is possible to have brackets between a lambda symbol, i.e., "$\lambda$" and a dot "$.$"?
>
> That is, is possible to have such an expression:
> $$\lambda x (yz) p. M?$$

I would say **yes**, since we have to read the $(yz)$ in the example as one term. Thus, by considering two examples, in the first we have
$$(\lambda x (yz) p. xyxzp)abc \rightarrow_\beta ayazc,$$
while in the second
$$(\lambda x (yz) p. x(yz)p)abc \rightarrow_\beta abc,$$
since we are treating $yz$ as a single term, i.e., with $N \equiv yz$, we have $$(\lambda x (yz) p. x(yz)p)abc = (\lambda x N p. xNp)abc.$$

However, this leads me to a second question, namely:

> **Question 2:** Is
> $$(\lambda x (yz) p. x(yz)p)abc$$
> the same as
> $$(\lambda x (yz) p. xyzp)abc?$$

This time I would answer **no**, since an ideal machine would consider the $y$ and the $z$ as two separate terms in $(\lambda x (yz) p. xyzp)abc$. Hence, we would have
$$(\lambda x (yz) p. xyzp)abc \rightarrow_\beta ayzc.$$

---

Thus, is my reasoning correct?

As always, any feedback will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could maybe make something like this work depending on what you intended it to mean, but it is *definitely* not common syntax, and you likely have a misconception somewhere. I would recommend minimizing the use of notational shortcuts. *Many* people get tripped up over the notation of the lambda calculus, and often due the notational shorthands *not* the "formal" syntax itself. To answer your first question, with respect to virtually all presentations of the untyped lambda calculus, the answer to Question 1 is an unambiguous "no". Question 2 is thus meaningless.

The "official" syntax of a lambda calculus is usually something like $E::= x \mid (\lambda x.E) \mid (E E)$. From there, a variety of shorthands are introduced. The relevant one in this case is that $\lambda xyz.E$ is short for $\lambda x.\lambda y.\lambda z.E$. The "official" syntax simply does not allow anything but a variable to occur between "$\lambda$" and "$.$" (and only allows exactly one). The shorthand just mentioned merely saves the hassle of writing "$\lambda$" multiple times, but it does not change this fact.

There are two ways that I could see allowing something like your syntax, though one I'd handle differently and neither lead to the behavior you describe. First, you could just want to allow multi-character identifiers and the parentheses would indicate that the contents should be treated as one identifier. In programming/specification languages, e.g. Haskell, this is usually handled by requiring whitespace between identifiers though. For example, $\lambda x\ yz\ p.E$. Another possibility is that you are adding pattern matching or at least destructuring binds. Pattern matching allows more complex syntax to appear where $\lambda$-bound variables can appear, but it is usually restricted as otherwise you get into really hairy undecidable and ambiguous territory. In this case, something like $(\lambda (yz).E)b$ would mean $b$ would attempt to be pattern matched against the pattern $yz$, but this is usually not an acceptable pattern. If you are interested in one approach that is fairly flexible in this regard but is *not* a lambda calculus, you can look at the [Pure Pattern Calculus](https://doi.org/10.1007/11693024_8).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Actually I had in mind something related to programming, so your reference to Haskell is particularly nice, even if at the moment I don't know much about that language. Actually, at the beginning I thought that the answer to question 1 was no, but then it was thinking in terms of programming languages that I came with the idea that maybe the answer was going to be yes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the first question is no, so the second question is meaningless. Let us see why the answer to the first question is negative.

The syntax of the $\lambda$-calculus is 
\begin{align}
 M, N ::= x \mid \lambda x.M \mid MN
\end{align}
which means that:

- every variable is a term,
- if $x$ is a variable and $M$ is a term then $\lambda x.M$ is a term,
- if $M$ and $N$ are terms then $MN$ is a term,
- anything else is a term.

There is no rule that allows you to say that if $M$ and $N$ are terms then $\lambda N.M$ is a term.
So, strictly speaking, given a term $M$, $\lambda xy.M$ is not a term. Conventionally, we set $\lambda x_1 x_2\dots x_n.M$ as a shorthand of $\lambda x_1. \lambda x_2. \dots \lambda x_n.M$.

Comment: As always, thanks a lot as always for your answer. As I wrote above as a comment to Derek Elkins answer, funnily enough at the beginning I thought that the answer to question 1 was no, but then it was thinking in terms of programming languages that I came with the idea that maybe the answer was going to be yes.